# how to i set props validation for an anonymous function

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am getting an error from eslint stating that {children} is missing in props validation but i am unsure how to approach this for an anonymous function

the error message i recieve from eslint:

```
src/Context/AuthContext.js
  Line 7:19:  'children' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

```
export default ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    AuthService.isAuthenticated().then((data) => {
      setUser(data.user);
      setIsAuthenticated(data.isAuthenticated);
      setIsLoaded(true);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {!isLoaded
        ? <h1>Loading</h1>
        : (
          <AuthContext.Provider value={{
            user, setUser, isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated,
          }}
          >
            {children}
          </AuthContext.Provider>
        )}
    </div>
  );
};

AuthContext.propTypes = {
  children: Proptypes.instanceOf(Object).isRequired,   //this doesnt work
};
```

Comment: `AuthContext` isn't a react component, so I'm not surprised that didn't work. Can you update your question to include the actual error message?

Comment: @DrewReese just edited it with the error message that eslint is giving me. i know that authContext isnt a function, not sure why i tried that. But i wasnt sure how to refer a anonymous function.

Comment: Does the `src/Context/AuthContext.js` file contain the component code from the snippet? You can always declare it normally and default export it later.

Comment: what i did is i just set the anonymous function to a variable and export defaulted it then set proptypes to the variable i assigned it to like this  const authenticator = ({ children }) => {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have a typo, should be `PropTypes`.

Moreover, `children` is a React node, so the proper type is `PropTypes.node`.

```
// Not Proptypes
PropTypes.instanceOf(Object).isRequired

// Should be
AuthContext.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
};
```

[See related docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes)